# how to find the depth of a concurrency bug

Tags: algorithm-analysis, concurrency, software-verification

How to find the depth of a concurrency bug

The below program runs on two separate threads and shares the variable x. Variables t1 and t2 are local to their threads. The program has a concurrency bug in it.

Bug: Any time both threads perform a read before they write we loose an update to x.

**Thread 1**

```
 1. t1=x
 2. t1=t1+1
 3. x=t1
```

**Thread 2**

```
 1. t2=x
 2. t2=t2+1
 3. x=t2
```

I am told the depth of the bug is 2. My question is what is the process to find the depth of a concurrency bug?

Answer (score 1):

The depth is the order of constraints (requirements in the order of execution before a bug is found) that a scheduler has to follow to find a bug. The issue that you are trying to solve here is a lost update that happens when you modify the X in both threads.
Let suppose the following sequence.
Thread 1 executes from line 1 and 2 then it jumps to thread 2 and executes it completely (first jump) then it jumps back to thread 2 (Second Jump) and it overwrite the value of X. It was necessary 2 jumps to trigger the problem, so the depth is 2.

Answer (score 1):

Each time a thread read the shared variable, increments the local variable, and writes back. Note that writing can occur by a thread only after the reading operation. So in the case of 2 threads, x can be incremented only once before writing back by a thread.